# I'm getting a "Can't open display" message when logging in via putty. Why?

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, putty

I'm running putty on Windows 7, logging into a Ubuntu 14.04 machine running KDE. My login is successful, but each time I get the message "Can't open display" immediately after the welcome message and before the shell prompt. I'm not trying to use X on this connection, I just want a shell, but I'm concerned that the error message indicates a deeper problem in the way Ubuntu is configured.

For what it's worth, X11 forwarding is not enabled in Putty for this session configuration.

Comment: do you have X server installed on your Windows?

Comment: Usually this sort of thing can be isolated to some program you are running in *your* shell initialization, e.g., `.bashrc`, and seen by turning on the shell trace (using "set -x").

Comment: @ThomasDickey - The set -x did it. Somehow or other the line 'xrandr --output VGA1...' got added to my .profile. Not sure how I managed that, or when, but problem solved. Thanks very much for the help.

Comment: @ThomasDickey - if you format your comment as an answer, I'll accept it. Not sure how to accept a comment if it's even possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually this sort of thing can be isolated to some program you are running in your shell initialization, e.g., .bashrc, and seen by turning on the shell trace (using "set -x").

Occasionally programs that you install will (helpfully) update your shell initialization if they are not designed to be installed as **`root`**, though more often it is just leftovers from testing new configurations.